# How to keep only some keywords in text file

Tags: parsing, email, text

I have a text file with some emails inside. I need to remove all emails without keywords inside (ie: gmail, yahoo...).
Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large is the file, would it fit into memory. How do you separate the emails within the file?

Comment: The file is about 1Mb and emails. I have separated emails with line break.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In which language do you want it?

example in Smalltalk:

```
((FileStream fileNamed: 'emails.txt') 
    substrings: eMailSeparatorChar) 
    reject: [:a|a includesSubString: aKeyWord]
```

Comment: I have never used Smalltalk, but it seems to be like Obj-C... I'll try this as soon as possible. I don't want specific language, since it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each email is in single line

```
grep -wEi 'gmail|yahoo|aol' emailFile
```

-w for words

-i Case insensitive

emailFile is the file containing emails .

following changes the input file.

```
grep -wEi 'gmail|yahoo|aol' emailFile > tempFile && cp tempFile emailFile && rm tempFile
```

If you want to add more to the list just add '|' serviceProvide